# UIView jumps down at beginning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I need to change `UIView` position on scroll of `tableview`. When i change the frame size of `UIView` in the animation block it goes down and than move to correct position. Please look at my code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGPoint scrollVelocity = [_collectionViewLeaderboard.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:_collectionViewLeaderboard.superview];
if (scrollVelocity.y > 0.0f){
    NSLog(@"going down");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              animations:^ {

                                  _headerview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _headerview.frame.size.width, _headerview.frame.size.height);

                                  _headerviewSecond.frame = CGRectMake(0, _headerview.frame.size.height, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.width, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height);

                                  self.collectionViewLeaderboard.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height+_headerview.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

                                  frameconditon = _headerview.frame;

                              } completion:^ (BOOL completed) {

                              }];

}
else if (scrollVelocity.y < 0.0f){
    NSLog(@"going up");

    //CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, _headerview.frame.origin.x, _headerview.frame.origin.y);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"test");


            _headerview.frame = CGRectMake(0, -(_headerview.frame.size.height), _headerview.frame.size.width, _headerview.frame.size.height);

            _headerviewSecond.frame = CGRectMake(0, (_headerview.frame.size.height)-40, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.width, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];


         self.collectionViewLeaderboard.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, _headerviewSecond.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

 }
 }
```

`headerview` should move to top of view and it work but when i run it first time, it goes down and back to correct postion. How will i change constraints at the time of scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constraint based views try to animate through changing constraints constant property using an outlet.